# Where can I find meta tags on WordPress website ? (Screwed up by a hacker)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My website was recently hacked (shared hosting and using wordpress framework). Although I have already removed all the spam content and changed the password, it appears that the hacker also changed the meta descriptions and now when you search the web site on google, the description is all wrong.

Website :- [rebrightpartners.com](http://rebrightpartners.com)

I tried to find the location of those meta tags but cannot find them.

Another thing to note is that the website is a bilingual website, and hence when you go to rebrightpartners.com, it will redirect you to rebrightpartners.com/en . Although when you search "rebright partners" on google, the site description and the url there is rebrightpartners.com.

Comment: I don't see any question in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found out was wrong. It was not the META tags on the website which were effecting the results, but it was the Google search console where the problem lied. The malicious content on the website was indexed by google and was displaying an incorrect description. Within a day after removing all those links, the description reverted back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress, by default doesn't have META Tags..

There are a number of plugins available that will add META tags..

Yost!  For example has a tool that does this.

Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0):

You can add meta content manually in theme files (tied to e.g. custom fields). Or, use a plugin like [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/screenshots/)